# How do I calculate the magnitude of a 2 vector whose components are very large?

Tags: delphi, pascal, freepascal

I'm working with an algorithm that generates numbers larger than the `Extended` type allows, which leads to runtime errors.

```
var 
  a, b, magn: Extended;
...
a := -3,6854775808e-3109;
b := 2,3020377564e+3549;
magn:= a * a + b * b; //EInvalidOp, "invalid floating point operation"
```

How can I solve this problem?

---

I'm writing the algorithm SmbPitchShift Site http://www.dspdimension.com c + + to pascal. If someone has it in Pascal, I will thank

Comment: Is your goal to get a meaningful result, or just to get it to overflow to +Infinity?

Comment: You have asked two completely separate questions here. The first one I can answer. The second one I cannot. This is why you are strongly recommended to ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 1):

If you really do want the square of the magnitude of the vector then that's not possible. That really is an overflow.

If you actually want the magnitude, then you can avoid the overflow like this:

```
function Magnitude(const a, b: Extended): Extended;
//calculate Sqrt(a*a + b*b) avoiding overflow
var
  x, y: Extended;
begin
  x := abs(a);
  y := abs(b);
  if x=0.0 then begin
    Result := y;
  end else if y=0.0 then begin
    Result := x;
  end else if x>y then begin
    Result := x*System.Sqrt(1.0+Sqr(y/x));
  end else begin
    Result := y*System.Sqrt(1.0+Sqr(x/y));
  end;
end;
```

In my experience, using the inefficient, non-standard `Extended` type rather than `Double` is usually indicative of a problem with your algorithm. Invariably there is a way to express the algorithm using `Double` arithmetic.

Comment: I think it will solve, I'm writing the algorithm SmbPitchShift Site http://www.dspdimension.com c + + to pascal. If someone has it in Pascal, I will thank

Comment: C++ seldom uses Extended (which is long double, usually), and rather uses float (Single in Delphi) or double (Double). I find the numbers rather large for a pitch shift library, actually. Are you sure you translated it properly?

Comment: smbPitchShift() uses floats everywhere (except for smbATan2()), so I doubt you really need such large values. Only atan2 uses doubles, are you sure you translated that correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, the problem is the exception, rather than the overflow. The logical solution would be to use SSE2 based math which allows for saturation rather than overflow. (IOW if something overflows, it changes to the highest valid number in the type)

To my best knowledge, Delphi does not currently support SSE2 code generation or intrinsics that would make this doable in higher level language.

But since a 64-bit Delphi is imminent, and x86_64 generally favours SSE2 over FPU, that might change short term.

Comment: The underlying problem is that the translation is broken. But for the question, my answer is THE way to calculate mag without overflowing at all.